# Python MySQL OperationalError: 1045, "Access denied for user root@'localhost'

Tags: python, mysql

I was trying to access the database from my python program by:

```
db = mysql.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'Max', passwd = 'maxkim', db = 'TESTDB')
cursor = db.cursor()
```

But, I get an error message in the first line of code.

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'Max'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

To remedy the situation, I did the following:

```
$ mysql -u Max-p
Enter password: maxkim

mysql> create database TESTDB;
mysql> grant usage on *.* to Max@localhost identified by ‘maxkim’;
mysql> grant all privileges on TESTDB.* to Max@localhost ;
mysql> exit
```

If I have granted all access to the the database for the user "Max" (me), why can't I still connect in python?

Answer (score 8):

You can try adding *GRANT OPTION* at the end:

```
GRANT all privileges on TESTDB.* to 'Max'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'maxkim' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You can also use the below command to find the grants for a user:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'Max'@'localhost';
```

**Also See**:

- [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10299148/1679863)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to everyone to always use **mysql_setpermission** rather than direct MySQL statements, **mysql_setpermission** does everything for you including FLUSHing. Any other way is prone to mistakes.